# Complex long to wide reshape algorithm

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have a problem where I need to reshape a long format data table into a wide format with non-overlapping entries based on ID1 and ID2. The logic is quite complex and depends on 3 columns ("Seq, "ID1" and "ID2").

Value_1 belonging to ID1 should be summed if it 'overlaps' with ID2 and vice-versa but only for distinct ID's.

See below for an input example and output, hope that clarifies it.

**input:**

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(Seq = c(9143L, 916L, 9293L, 9301L, 9302L, 9304L, 
9305L, 9306L, 9307L, 931L, 9311L), ID1 = c("ID1_1", "ID1_1", 
NA, "ID1_2", "ID1_2", NA, "ID1_3", "ID1_3", "ID1_3", "ID1_4", 
"ID1_4"), value_1 = c(30L, 30L, NA, 30L, 30L, NA, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
50L, 50L), ID2 = c(NA, NA, "ID2_1", "ID2_2", "ID2_3", "ID2_4", 
"ID2_4", "ID2_4", "ID2_4", "ID2_4", "ID2_5"), value_2 = c(NA, 
NA, 33L, 200L, 46L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

**output:**

[image: output]

(notice for example the last row, value_1 = 80 because 30+50 from summing up the values belonging to ID1_3 and ID1_4)

Comment: I can't see where is the pivot in the problem. It seems to me you have a logic ```` df1 <- df %>% mutate( value_2 = if(ID_1 == ID_2, value_1 + value_2, value_2))````. Could you elaborate the logic better?

Comment: in fairness he never mentions pivot, though he uses the terms wide and long, but perhaps without knowledge of the pivot_x functions.

Comment: I clarified it a bit in the table, I hope that helps

Comment: You write that "The logic is quite complex", but the only description you provide is "...summed if it 'overlaps'..."  where 'overlaps' are not defined... ;) Please describe the logic more thoroughly, and walk us through a representative case, rather leaving the deciphering to us. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `rleid()` function from data.table package, which is a fascinating function to calculate run-length encoding.  Do it like this

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(d = cumsum( c(0, diff(rleid(ID1))) != 0 & c(0, diff(rleid(ID2))) != 0),
         value_1 = value_1 * c(1, diff(rleid(ID1))),
         value_2 = value_2 * c(1, diff(rleid(ID2)))) %>% group_by(d) %>%
  summarise(Seq = toString(Seq),
            value_1 = sum(value_1, na.rm = T),
            value_2 = sum(value_2, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-d)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Seq                               value_1 value_2
  <chr>                               <int>   <int>
1 9143, 916                              30       0
2 9293                                    0      33
3 9301, 9302                             30     246
4 9304, 9305, 9306, 9307, 931, 9311      80     104
```

**Old answer**

```
df %>% group_by(d = cumsum( c(0, diff(rleid(ID1))) != 0 & c(0, diff(rleid(ID2))) != 0)) %>%
  summarise(Seq = toString(Seq),
            value_1 = sum(unique(value_1), na.rm = T),
            value_2 = sum(unique(value_2), na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-d)
```

Comment: Though, you have accepted the answer, I revised it a bit to handle the cases where two values in different ids but in same group are same.  `unique()` will not handle these properly.  Check revised answer

Comment: Thanks, yes and I had to do df %>% arrange(ID1,ID2) %>% ....  , I think it works :)

Comment: Ohh! I assumed your df is already arranged

Comment: Actually, I run into problems where the ID1 and ID2 are not consecutive anymore and sorting doesn't work. But thanks for all the help !

Comment: I fixed it by using igraph() grouping on the ID1 and ID2 columns and used that instead for the  'd' variable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I really like AnilGoyal's solution. I can see that I need to start using the data.table package.

That being said, I was working on a dplyr approach sans data.table, which is conspicuously more verbose. Also, it took me awhile to figure out what to do with duplicate values. Multiplying by the `changei` column (0 or 1) removed duplicates. The following was my approach:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, replace_na, "NA") %>% 
  mutate(
    change1 = ID1 != lag(ID1, default = "Start"),
    value_1 = value_1 * change1,

    change2 = ID2 != lag(ID2, default = "Start"),
    value_2 = value_2 * change2,

    change = cumsum(change1 & change2)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(change) %>% 
  summarise(
    Seq = toString(Seq),
    value_1 = sum(value_1, na.rm = T),
    value_2 = sum(value_2, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The result was:

```
df
#   change Seq                               value_1 value_2
#    <int> <chr>                               <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1 9143, 916                              30       0
# 2      2 9293                                    0      33
# 3      3 9301, 9302                             30     246
# 4      4 9304, 9305, 9306, 9307, 931, 9311      80     104
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as succinct as above, but a Base R solution none the less:

```
# Function to calculate the aggregate value: .agg_func => function() 
.agg_func <- function(df, id_col, value_col){
  sbst <- subset(
    df, 
    !(is.na(df[,id_col])) & !(duplicated(df[,id_col])),
    select = c(id_col, value_col)
  )
  return(sum(sbst[,value_col], na.rm = TRUE))
}

# Function to group data by ids: .grouping_func => function() 
.grouping_func <- function(df, id_col){
  r_l_e <- rle(df[,id_col])
  rle_id <- rep(seq_along(r_l_e$values), times = r_l_e$lengths)
  return(c(0, diff(rle_id)) != 0)
}

# Group the data: grpd_df => data.frame 
grpd_df <- transform(
  df, 
  grp = cumsum(
    apply(
      vapply(
        names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "ID")],
        function(x).grouping_func(df, x),
        logical(nrow(df))
        ), 
      1,
      all
    )
  )
)  

# Split-apply-combine the aggregate function to the grouped data: 
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(with(grpd_df, split(grpd_df, grp)), function(s){
        data.frame(
          Seq = toString(s$Seq), 
          value_1 = .agg_func(s, "ID1", "value_1"), 
          value_2 = .agg_func(s, "ID2", "value_2")
        )
      }
    )
  ), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```